# django maximum recursion depth exceeded when making calculation

Tags: django

I'm trying to do a calculation here. If the install choice is equal to 'FIRST' then the amount entered should be subtracted from the fee and return the balance, else the amount should be subtracted from the previous balance (FIRST will always be captured before the other choices).

```
class Payment(models.Model):

   fee = models.ForeignKey(
      Fee
   )

   installment = models.CharField(
       _('Installment'),
       max_length=30,
       choices=INSTALLMENT_CHOICES,
       default=u' ',
       null=False,
       blank=False
   )

   amount = models.FloatField(
       _('Amount'),
       null=False,
       blank=False,
       default=0.00

   )

   @property
   def balance(self):
      if self.installment == "FIRST":
          return self.fee.totalannualfee - self.amount
      else:
          return self.balance - self.amount
```

But I'm however getting this error if the installment choice is not FIRST:

RuntimeError at /admin/sisdatasources/payment/

maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Because you're calling `return self.balance` inside `balance` property, so it ends up infinitely calling `balance` property until `maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: But is there another way to do the condition without running into recursion?